# Как повесить событие на генерируемый динамический элемент?

Tags: javascript

есть элемент списка  `<li class='item'>` который генерируется автоматически.
как можно на него повесить событие?
addEventListener не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "li.item", function(e) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Вместо `document` используйте изначально существующий родительский элемент, ближайший к месту вставки `li`.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("item") || e.target.closest(".item"))
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
});
```

Comment: а как можно на нативном js это сделать?